# Орфоэпическая норма для слова «шериф»

Tags: орфоэпия

В Америке, как и во многих других странах, существует в полиции такая должность, как шериф. Обычно таким людям дают специальные значки ([см.](http://data:image/jpeg;base64,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)). Но сейчас мы не об этом. :) Вопрос: как произносить слово: [шериф] или [шриф]? Мне кажется, оба варианта возможны. Первый точно имеет право на существование, но второй...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что нет оснований произносить это слово без гласной, на которую в исходном слове даже падает ударение. Трудностей произношение "шериф" не вызывает, а в разговоре (видимо, для такого случая предлагается упрощение) это редко потребуется, скорее встретится в озвученном фильме или при чтении вслух.

Comment: Я как-то и не подумал, что следует смотреть на оригинал. В [этом видео](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBI2rsI7Hug) говорится, что ударение падает на первый слог. Всё-таки ударение ставится на первый слог, да... Второй вариант просто часто услышать можно, поэтому и возник вопрос.